# $_Session Array unidentified index

Tags: php, arrays, session, merge

I have class named Country->Gov->Branch. Each one of them returns an array to the other in this order : Country gives Gov and merges it with gov, gov gives branch and merges it with branch. Branch array is an attribute of User class when I use User and load it into `$_session` , I do merge the Branch array to session directly using array merge to make it easy to use so I dont have to loop array of array (Just an idea). The result of `print_r($_SESSION);` was as follows

```
Array ( [userid] => 1 
        [login] => email@gmail.com 
        [name] => Mohamed Talaat 
        [group] => 0 
        [picture] => mac 
        [Branchbranchid] => 1 
        [Branchbranchname] => Head Office 
        [Branchaddress] => xxxxxx st. , xxxx 
        [Branchgovid] => 2 
        [Govgovid] => 2 
        [Govgovcode] => 03 
        [Govgovname] => Alexandria 
        [Govcountryid] => 1 
        [Countrycountryid] => 1 
        [Countrycountrycode] => 20 
        [Countrycountryname] => Egypt )
```

I said Horray , but the happy feelings don`t last forever when I call it in the way below, I get an error.

```
echo $_SESSION['Branchbranchid'];
```

**Notice: Undefined index: Branchbranchid in D:\xampp\htdocs\office\home.php on line 7**
and nothing is echoed 
I do have a `session_start();` at the first head of the page before any code , i notice the problem happened at the merged part starting from the key **[Branchbranchid]** because if i do `echo $_session['any element'];` like

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Before this key (**[Branchbranchid]**), the code works fine. I tried to turn around by adding values with keys to another array but I get the same result and the same notice appear and nothing is echoed. I think there is a problem in the keys because when I have pushed the values to an indexed array, its working fine but without the keys, it is a lost case ...

Any ideas ... about why and How to avoid or to fix this issue

Comment: to use session in any way you have to add `session_start();` on top of the pages on which you want to use it

Comment: Where are you using this, on the same file or any other php file?

Comment: `$_SESSION ` != `$_session`

Comment: i do have a session_start(); at the first line of the page, and i do have 2 files first is index.php that i have initialize the $_session in it and do the array_merge in it , and second file home.php that i will use the $_session in it to display $_session values or use it , when i do `print_r($_session);` i do have the result that appears in the question above

Comment: Thanks Charlotte i do use it as you said $_SESSION at the code and i will repair it at the question

Comment: Class Country -> getCountry() = return array of Countries
Class Gov do Call Country -> getCountry() and do merge with Gov array and do have a function getGov() = that return array of Gov and merged branches,same is Branch which is an attribute at a User Class
User class at index.php to do login func. the session and and array of Branch is merged using array_merge($_SESSION,$user->getBranch());
getBranch return an array of merged arrays when use any element of the merged array that is returned from getbranch print_r or traverse in it by using foreach the keys are printed fine and values too

Answer (score 0):

You should put `start_session()` as first line in your php file wherever you are trying to access the global session.

And change the `$_session` with `$_SESSION`

Comment: I do use start_session at the first line and in my code i do write it $_SESSION in uppercase ... i do repair the question above Thanks